What would happen if a bunch of liquid helium was dropped onto a city
Suppose we have a weapon that converts all the air in an area into liquid helium. Evil empire number 1234 wants to use this weapon to destroy the environment that any goody two shoes rebels might live in. So they make this weapon but the trouble I am having is if this would actually be effective at its purpose at making an area unlivable for a mediocre amount of time. What would the effects of such a weapon look like if it was used?

All the air in new york city sized area reaching 1 km high will be converted to liquid helium.

It will remain liquid helium until it hits something

By destruction I mean making the area too cold to live in for at least 5 days/ freezing everything in the area such as water, people, and buildings.

It will be used in a city practically identical to new york

It will be converted to an equivalent volume of liquid helium



How do you mean "All the air in a new york city"? Just the air up to the top of the average building, or to the top of the atmosphere? Would that include air inside people's lungs?

I edited it to accommodate your suggestion

Will the air be converted to an equivalent volume of liquid helium, or will the mass of the air be converted to liquid helium?  An equivalent mass of liquid helium would (at least initially) occupy a volume < 1% of the atmosphere it replaces.  Assuming the helium is contiguous and occupies only part of the space, you'd also have to consider the shockwave as the atmosphere rushes into the sudden vacuum.   If it's equivalent volume, the city doesn't have time to freeze as it's instantly crushed under a hundred times the mass it had to bear up a moment before.

Obligatory what-if - a by-volume replacement would closely resemble this, though helium is more compressible than water.  Also, the mass involved is enormously greater, because despite helium's lower density, the volume involved is hundreds of times greater.   Freezing would be secondary to simple compressive force.

I replaced it with equivalent volume

Quite aside from the destructive potential of the helium itself regardless of its capacity as a heat sink, its capacity as a heat sink is also dictated by the mass/volume question, as a by-volume replacement represents a much greater heat sink capacity than a by-mass.

@jdunlop Forvthe by-volume version, don't forget the explosive force of cubic miles of liquid helium rapidly expanding as it ceases to be a liquid because the medium around it is so much warmer...

@Jedediah - remember, the OP specified that the helium remains liquid  (by magic) until it hits something, so only the surface of the volume in contact with the ground would begin explosive expansion (at first).

@jdunlop Ah, I missed that bit.

Everything is Crushed, Freezing is Secondary
Replacing a kilometre of air with liquid helium results in a uniform pressure in excess of 1.26 MPa suddenly applied to everything in the city.  Vehicles are crushed, buildings crumble, people are crushed.  All of this happens well before any heat is transferred.  More complicated effects would start to occur as the liquid "settles", causing complex currents within the body of liquid, all mechanically destructive as well.
The enthalpy of liquid helium at boiling is 20.754 kJ/kg.  NYC has an area of ~728 square km, but we'll round that up to 750 for convenience.  750 cubic kilometres of liquid helium would mass 125e9 kg, so approximately 2.5 petajoules would have to be consumed from the environment.  If this is your average sunny day, it'd take about an hour for the sun to deliver that much energy to the region.  So things won't be frozen for long.  (Unless the local weather is < 0C, in which case things will stay frozen as long as they typically remain frozen.)
However.  Helium has an expansion ratio of 1:745 - greater than nitrogen!  So the effect of the immediate commencement of boiling for this enormous volume of liquid helium is going to cause hurricane-force and extremely chilly winds to sweep through the region for the better part of a day.  The whole area is going to be unseasonably cold for a while.
--
Edit: Also, as a result of that expansion ratio, the local atmosphere will probably be unbreathable for a few hours until the helium is forced up to the edge of the atmosphere.

TL:DR; helium has terrible heat capacity, but drop a km of any liquid on a city and the city will be crushed.

Crushed, scraped away to frozen bedrock, and exploded. 5kJ/kg average gravitational potential energy and 20kJ/kg enthalpy of vaporization = almost a quarter of the helium is vapor by the time it hits bottom, just from gravity. Nothing whatsoever remains.

@gs - the OP did specify that the helium stays liquid "until it hits something".  I assume space magic.

I might not understand your question
If I do...

You want to take all of the atmosphere above New York City up to 1km in altitude above the city...
Regardless its actual composition you want to convert the volume of gas to molecular helium...
Then you want to cause everything from the ground to 1km above the city to freeze such that the helium will be liquid...
Then you want to keep it that cold for at least 5 days, but before that...
The liquid helium will drop onto the city.

First, because you had the chutzpah to tag this science-based, let's consider what would actually happen

Nothing converts from gas to liquid instantly.
Atmosphere close to the ground will condense on buildings and streets, but most will fall like rain.
For a couple of minutes, everybody in New York City will sound like Alvin and the Chipmunks. During this time all the pigeons fall to the ground, dead as door nails.
Shortly thereafter, everybody will die of asphyxiation long before the helium condenses to a liquid.
If anyone survives that long, they'll die of hypothermia long before the liquid helium is an issue.
Most of the people on the subway survive, unless all that atmosphere converted, too, then they all die at about the same time as the pigeons. The subway cars careen into the first stopped train on the circuit, causing a spectacular crash that nobody sees.
Eventually, all the trees in Central Park will freeze. Some will fall over as the liquid helium on the ground compromises their roots, but most just lose their branches.

OK, that's boring. Let's convert to science-fiction and see if that helps
Tohtori Paha invents the Atmospheric Helium Condensing System (AHCS) and unleashes it upon an unsuspecting New York City because it's too liberal for a Trump-led White House to pay the ransom to save it!

The AHCS is a fleet of one MILLION drones, each having a helium condenser and a whomping big and well insulated bag.
The drones fill each bag with ONE THOUSAND GALLONS (Woo-Hoo!) liquid helium!
On Tohtori Paha's (or Tohtori Pahan, if you're paying attention... and if I'm remembering correctly) command ONE BILLION GALLONS of liquid helium is dropped from 1km above that very same unsuspecting New York City!

And just to make sure nothing goes wrong!

The Good Tohtori Paha unleashes another MILLION DRONES to surround the falling helium with refrigeration to make sure it stays liquid before it hits the ground!

Tune in next wee...
I'm not waiting that long.
When the liquid begins to contact anything, things begin to shatter. Especially glass. People inside the buildings are presently safe, but people on the streets and in vehicles die a horrifying and gruesome death! No, they're not frozen clear through. There's not enough liquid helium to do that. They die of shock. (New York City is 784 km2 I guess I should have used liters, but that's only 1.27 gallons per square meter. I wonder if converting the atmosphere as requested would even add up to a billion gallons.... anyway, back to our story!)
The people in the buildings get cool, maybe even cold. Those in older buildings with poor (or manually activated) heating systems get very cold. Folks in modern buildings probably don't even notice what's going on (it's New York, after all) unless they're near one of the shattered windows. (Automated air conditioning would turn on heat as needed... and don't forget the volume of those buildings! The handful of gallons that fall on the roof and down the sides is a pitiful fraction of what would be needed to actually do something inside the buildings.) The windows, of course, are breaking outwards as the hotter and therefore higher air pressure inside the buildings forces the glass out onto the streets, where even more people die even more gruesome deaths.
Then, because nothing short of magic (which has little to do with the science-based tag) can keep the liquid helium liquid for very long, the helium begins to revert to its gaseous state.
And a lot more people die from asphyxiation.
But, despite Tohtori Paha's frightful efforts, the helium evaporates in less than a day, forcing ex-mayor Cuomo to call on a few friends to support soup kitchens for the traumatized New Yorkers who survived (most of whom don't actually realize that anything happened... Hey! I'm walkin' here!).
